# How to add a number just one time instead of doubling it in a loop?

Tags: python

I am fresh in the world of python and I need to do this exercise for college:

> Write a function that calculates the quotient and remainder of the
> integer division between two numbers. Use only operations addition and
> subtraction to calculate the result. Tip: use a repetition structure
> for this. Make a main program that takes the dividend and divisor of
> the user and, after calling the function, displays the quotient and
> the rest.

I know how to do it, except the part where I add a quotient to a quotient

**For example:**

Instead of going: `5+5=10+5=15+5=20...`  I'm doing: `5+5=10+10=20`

I know it's hard to understand but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this.

**Code**

```
def solution(dividend, divisor):
    quotient = 0
    negative = 1
    if divisor == 0:
        print("0 Division Error.")
        return
    if dividend < 0:
        negative *= -1
        dividend *= -1
    if divisor < 0:
        negative *= -1
        divisor *= -1
        
    while (dividend - divisor) >= 0:
        quotient += 1
        dividend -= divisor
    
    print(f"Quotient- {negative * quotient}")
    print(f"Reminder- {dividend}")


solution(20,8)
```

**Output**

```
Quotient- 2
Reminder- 4
```

**This code also handles the edge cases.**

Comment: bro, thank you so much, i've been trying to solve this for hours. you're my savior

Comment: Your welcome @CaueZanat. Don't forget to mark it right for others to know that you got your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables, so that you always keep the original value constant, and only modify a "total" variable. For exmaple:

```py
start = 5
total = 0

for i in range(5)
    total += start
    print(total)
```

Which gives the output

```
5
10
15
20
25
```

Comment: bro, can you show me an example of that ? i thought about doing it, but i can't figure it out how to...

Comment: I've edited my original comment to include one